# Navigation drawer with fragment on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I am trying to implements this tutorial https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer After using a splashscreen, I've did everything, but my problem is the fragment after the splashscreen, I don't know if I did this correctly:

The folders here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qdTg.png

Home.java (fragment (first link of navigation)):

```
public class Home extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /**
     * Inflate the layout for this fragment
     */
    return inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
}
```

}

MainActivity (splashscreen)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Thread logoTimer = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                int logoTimer = 0;
                while (logoTimer < 5) {
                    sleep(1000);
                    logoTimer = logoTimer + 1;
                }
                ;
                startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.Home"));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    logoTimer.start();
}
```

}

I added the fragment Home in the Manifest:

```
<activity
android:name=".Home"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.Home" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

But i get a error in the manifest, i think, its not the nice way to use and call the fragment after the splashscreen, how to do that ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fragment is not an Activity. You don't need to add it in your Manifest file.

Comment: Well, how i create a Fragment and call it after the splashscreen ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use
`startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.Home"));`

because its a fragment not an activity....
use

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
      FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
      fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
      Home frag = new Home();
fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, frag );
```

try this..this will work

Comment: "Wrong second argument type" @asad.qazi

Comment: you can follow a fragments tutorial... This is a sample one...
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm
if u don't understand let me know then

Comment: `Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: '....Home', required: 'android.app.Fragment' less... 

replace
(int,
android.app.Fragment)
in FragmentTransaction cannot be applied
to
(int,
....Home)`
 
Home.java:
`public class Home extends Fragment {`

Comment: Yes you've to change your home fragment from
public class Home extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {....
to
public class Home extends android.app.Fragment {

Comment: Thanks but here an another problem `public void addNavItem(String navTitle, String windowTitle, Class<? extends Fragment> fragmentClass) {
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navTitle));
        drawerAdapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getActivity(), navDrawerItems);
        lvDrawer.setAdapter(drawerAdapter);
        drawerNavItems.add(new FragmentNavItem(windowTitle, fragmentClass));
    }`

`dlDrawer.addNavItem("First", "First Fragment",Home.class);`
"3rd argument type'java.lang.Class<fr.solutis.solutis.Home>', required: 'java.lang.Class<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment>'"

Comment: Now its woking:
`    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Home frag = new Home();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, frag);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }`
But the navigation wont appear

Comment: The navigation drawer, wait i do a new answer and post the fresh code, because i did a lot of changes

Comment: Look bottom my answer